# Replicate just one table on slave from master in mysql

Tags: mysql, replication, master-slave

Is it possible to replicate only a single table from master DB to slave DB? 
For example my master DB name is master.db with four tables and on my slave.db there is no table. I want to replicate only one table on my slave from my master DB. How can I configure master and slave my.cnf files to achieve this? What extra parameters should I add in my.cnf files for both master and slave?

Note: The master DB has multiple slaves, this slave DB is one of them.

Answer (score 4):

You should investigate parameters like `replicate_do_table=yourtable`in your slave my.cnf file

see [http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_replicate-do-table)

This basically tells the database to only replicate certain tables. There are also options for wildcards. Read it carefully though as there are certain caveats depending on your setup.

Comment: thanx alot.do i have to add --replicate-do-table=yourtable in [mysqld] section?

Comment: that's right, add it at a convenient point in the [mysqld] section

Comment: After adding replicate-do-table=yourtable in [mysqld] section slave.db is not getting start :/

Comment: If you look at the error log, it should tell you what the problem is. In this case I think it is a typo on my part. Try `replicate_do_db=yourtable` in your my.cnf file