# select * from one machine insert to another

Tags: python, mysql

There are 2 machines

```
server = 192.168.10.10
slave = 192.168.10.100
```

they have data base named test1 also have same tables
I want to select all from a `table(base2)` on a `database(test1)` on server and drop the same `table(base2)` on slave and insert all data to it every X min .

```
conMaster = pymysql.connect(host=masterIp1, user=masterUser1, password=masterPass1, 
database=dataBase1)
conSlave = pymysql.connect(host=slaveIp1, user=slaveUser1, password=slavePass1, database=dataBase1)
curMaster = conMaster.cursor()
curSlave = conSlave.cursor()
#consider we know the table name and in both servers table name is base2
masterData=curMaster.execute("select * from base2")
SlaveData=curSlave.execute("select * from base2")
#if base2 on master server has 10 more rows than slave master
#consider database name is test1 in both servers
if len(masterData)>len(SlaveData)+10:
   curSlave.execute("drop table base2"
   "create table test1.base2"
   "insert test1.base2"
   "select * from ??"
   )
```

since `cur.slave.execute` references to slave server, when I want to `select * from base2` on master server I don't know how to write the code.

Comment: Why don't you set up replication rather than reinventing the wheel?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to replicate that table from master to slave. Maybe this helps you:
[Replicate just one table on slave from master in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28556761/replicate-just-one-table-on-slave-from-master-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

I know i have to use addlinkserver
like this

```
curSlave.execute("insert into test1.base1 "
                 "exec sp_addlinkedserver  @ server =  '192.168.1.100' "
                 "select * from  + '192.168.1.100'.test1.dbo.base1 ")
```

but syntax is not right.
server is not always online and every day at the end of work hours i turn it off so replication is not reliable and master-slave will be asynchronous .
i solve the problem of having several tables so if you could correct the code above ,it will be done .